# apache hive integration with apache beam

Tags: hive, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am doing a `POC` to connect to Apache Hive in the Apache Beam pipeline and i am getting exception similar to the below SO link. I did change the version of the `JDBC driver` to the latest. But still facing the issue.

As mentioned in the below link it was due to cluster issue. If anyone can help me out about the issue clearly i can guide my corresponding team with that issue and get it resolved.

If you need any other information,i will provide you with that.

[Apache Beam - org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Method not supported)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44901372/apache-beam-org-apache-beam-sdk-util-usercodeexception-java-sql-sqlexception)

Comment: The suggestion in that answer is to update the Hive JDBC driver version, rather than the version of JdbcIO.

Comment: Yeah sorry i mean to say that only. Sorry for the wrong update the JDBC driver version i am using is latest one 2.3.2.
in that link it is mentioned that the issue is with the cluster. So i wanted to know what will be that.

Comment: Hi Sri, Did you get solution for this? Can you please share code?